# Selected item in listview diffrent approaches

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a question. Two approaches below correctly bind `selected item` for `listview`. `Approach 1` seems to be much simpler and quicker, `Approach 2` seems to be more code consuming. Is there anything else that's makes difference between those two approaches or this is doing exactly the same? My only concern is whether `Approach 2` works in `TwoWay` `mode` by default and can it be changed to another `mode`?
Thanks for the info.

**Approach 1:**

```
<ListView SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedOrder, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}">
..
</ListView>
```

**Approach 2:**

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}" ItemSelected="OnPlaylistSelected">
..
</ListView>
```

This also requires this in code behind of course:

```
void OnPlaylistSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
     _viewModel.SelectOrderCommand.Execute(e.SelectedItem);
}
```

Comment: both are equivalent.  Some people prefer an event approach, so prefer a MVVM approach.  ListView provides support for both methods

Comment: @Jason i think it's not even requires handler - i think in this particural case listview doesn;t have command possibility for this attribute therefore command has to be created on .cs level otherwise for other controls even if second approach is choosen direct command can be added into attribute P.S What about mode - what;s default in 2nd apprach and how to manipualte it?

Answer (score 1):

Having had a quick look at the docs, I cannot find a definitive answer myself:

[ListView Interactivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/interactivity)

If I were to hazard a guess though, I would suggest that if you are just wanting to assign something to SelectedItem and do nothing fancy, then Approach 1 is the way to go.

If however you wanted to do other things other than just set the SelectedItem, then you would go with Approach 2 as it will give you a bit more control over what is happening in the background.

Comment: and what about mode in case of 2nd approach - whats default and how to eventually configure it?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anything else that's makes difference between those two approaches or this is doing exactly the same?

The **Approach 1** uses the **TwoWay** binding model, and the **Approach 2** uses the **Default** binding model. But here the default model should also be `TwoWay`. Therefore, they should be the same.

**Generally** you don't need to go looking. Most of the controls behave as you would intuitively expect them to.

For example:

An `Entry` is two way by default because that's just what you would expect.
A `Label` is one way because... well... you can't set a label through the UI.
And so on.

The only time you really need to set binding mode explicitly is when you are deliberatly doing something out of the ordinary, like you want to use an `Entry` because you like the look but don't want the user to be able to enter a new value: That's a weird use-case for an entry so you probably need to explicitly set its binding mode.

And from the definition of [BindingMode Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.bindingmode?view=xamarin-forms), if using BindableProperty to bind, the default value should be `OneWay`.

- **Default** : When used in Bindings, indicates that the Binding should use the [DefaultBindingMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.bindableproperty.defaultbindingmode?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_BindableProperty_DefaultBindingMode). When used in BindableProperty declaration, defaults to `BindingMode.OneWay`.

If you want to modify the binding model on runtime, you could use code to do that,

```
listview.SetBinding<StoreDetailViewModel>(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, vm =>vm.items,mode: BindingMode.TwoWay);
```